# How do I check programatically if an AWS lambda is already running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda and I would like to ensure that there is only one instance of it running at a time.

Is it possible for a lambda (written in python) to check if another instance of that same lambda is already running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure that no more than 1 instance of your function is running, the easiest way is to set [reserved concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html#configuration-concurrency-provisioned) to **one**:

> Reserved concurrency also **limits the maximum concurrency** for the function, and applies to the function as a whole, including versions and aliases.

To check if this is actually the case, you can query [ConcurrentExecutions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html#monitoring-metrics-concurrency) metric on your function with `By Function Name` dimension:

> The number of **function instances** that are processing events.

To do it **programmatically**, you can use [get-metric-data](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-data.html) or [get-metric-statistics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html) calls.